# dante socks server went down after reannounce torrents

Tags: linux, proxy, socks, dante

When I reannounce many torrents on qbittorrent my Danted fall down.

```
/var/log: Jan 11 10:26:42 (1578738402.297782) danted[20286]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15



 firefox: Proxy refuses to accept connections
 Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that denies the connection.
 Check the proxy settings and make sure they are correct.
 Contact your system administrator to verify that the proxy server is working.



logoutput: stderr
user.privileged: proxy
user.unprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody
logoutput: syslog /var/log/danted.log
internal: eth0 port = 65525
external: eth0

socksmethod: username
user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: nobody

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: error
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    command: connect
    log: error
    socksmethod: username
}
```

So, dante won't work anymore, i need manual restart it which is bad solution. Can I fix it? I want reannoune torrent without restarting daemon everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Signal 15 is the SIGTERM signal, indicating a process should exit.  This means some process is sending the Dante server a signal indicating Dante should stop running and exit.

You can test this manually by doing "kill " from your shell to verify that Dante prints the same log message when you do so.  E.g., "kill 20286" if Dante's pid was 20286 as above.

To fix this you need to find out who and why some process is telling Dante to exit, which is not necessarily easy to do.